# How does String charAt() method work in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Why does the following code create compile error? Doesn't `charAt()` method return `char` datatype?

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String a = "abcd";
    char c = a.charAt(2)-'a';
}
```

`error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subtract two `char`s, they are promoted to `int` and the subtraction is performed on two `int` operands, and the result is an `int`.

You can cast to `char` to assign the result to a `char` :

```
char c = (char) (a.charAt(2)-'a');
```

Note that you might get unexpected results if the subtraction results in a negative value, since `char` can't contain negative values.

Besides, I'm not sure it makes any sense to subtract 'a' from a character and store the result in a `char`. In your example, it will give you the character whose numeric value is 2, which has no relation to the character 'c'.

Comment: but subtracting like this: `char c = 'b'-'a';` doesn't make any error! why is not that working like int then?

Comment: @agassaa Because your example in your comment is computed at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) says:

> - If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion
>   (§5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> - If either operand is of type double, the
>   other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type
>   float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand
>   is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both
>   operands are converted to type int.**

So you need to explicitly cast it to char to get rid of the possible lossy error

```
char c = (char) (a.charAt(2)-'a');
```

> Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type
> of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13)
> to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value
> set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

charAt() method return char type But you are subtracting two char that will return int value in this case it will be 2 . So receive it into int it will work.

int c =  a.charAt(2)-'a';